# Ruby: puts printing stderr of the result of a command

Tags: ruby, variables, stderr, puts

It's not clear to me how "puts" works in Ruby for the output of a command that throws its output to stderr.

Look at this code:

```
command="/usr/bin/java -version"
result=`#{command}`

puts result
puts "XX#{result}XX"
```

The result is:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

XXXX
```

java -version sends its output to stderr (I am aware that in order to prevent this I should have used 2>&1 at the end of the command)

My question: The variable "result" in reality is empty, but the first puts prints the stderr output and the second puts the stdout (which is empty). Why? What's going on?

Comment: Backticks still run the command and print its output. The *capture*, the return of the backticks, is stdout.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, both `puts` statements print nothing. If you do this:

```
puts "YY#{result}YY"
puts "XX#{result}XX"
```

You'll see that you get `YYYY` and `XXXX`.

The reason that you see the output from Java is because Java itself is printing to stderr which isn't being captured by Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The first `puts result` prints only newline. The output come from the following line (by the command itself, printing to stderr)

```
result=`#{command}`
```

You can confirm that by removing all `puts ...` lines.

Comment: Duh! I was fooled by myself! Thanks!